# CUPS will print ignoring the quotas set

Tags: cups, quotas

I set the quotas both ways(though lpadmin and by editing printers.conf) and neither seem to work(i did restart the daemon) but print requests are still granted with no error.
What is wrong?(i am running ubuntu linux 9.04)

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to do anything else but speculation if you don't provide a detailed record of what exactly your `lpadmin` command was, or what manipulation of the *printers.conf* file you made. (Also note, that direct editing of *printers.conf* is not recommended unless you do it while `cupsd` is stopped.)

CUPS' quotas do work for me. However, the last job crossing the quota threshold will always start printing, since CUPS does know about its number of pages only after starting to process the jobfile, not beforehand...

Comment: so if someone tries to print 100 pages in one job and the quota allows 4 more pages, cups will simply allow them to do it??

Comment: *"so if someone tries to print 100 pages in one job and the quota allows 4 more pages, cups will simply allow them to do it??"* -- Yes.

Comment: If you need a really powerful accounting software (which you can tweak into every imagineable direction) working with CUPS then have a look at PyKota (http://www.pykota.com/).